# How Use Shift With F2 in Vs2019

Tags: asp.net

I updated Visual Studio 2019, but I can't use shift+F2 to create new folders and files.
I tried different methods but it didn't work. How is it work?
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not really aware that shift F2 ever worked in Visual Studio?

You can certainly highlight a object in the project exploer and hit f2 to re-name.

but, to add a folder, web page, files etc?

Then simple right click on the  project like this:

[image]

So, right click on above, then choose add, and you get this:

[image]

From above, you can add new web pages, new folders, and even existing "items" (existing files).

So, I never used shift F2 - can't recall if it ever was used or worked.

but, you can as noted highlight any object in the project explorer and hit f2.

Comment: I do not mean to create a file this way. There is another shortcut I found. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install this extension to visual studio 2019:

[AddNewFile Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.AddNewFile)

After the install, you'll be able to press shift+ F2 to add new files of any type and folders with subfolders.

[working extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTkWh.png)